# Interaction between redux and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I was working on a function which loads some data to a component artificially ie. recreates a page display based on the uploaded data.
I am facing issues with when useEffect gets called.
Here is the code:

```
const funcA = (props) => {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    let b = [2, 3];
    setSelected(a);
    setParam(b);
    return (
        <div>...</div>
);
}

const funcB = (props) => {
    useEffect(
        () => {
            setParam([]);
        },
        [props.selected]
    );
    return (<div>...</div>);
}
```

`setSelected()` and `setParam()` are actions which modify my redux store.
Now When I change `selected` using `setSelected()` in `funcA`, useEffect is called in `funcB` which modifies the `param` data based on `selected` values.
I thought this should not be an issue as I am calling `setParam()` after calling `setSelected` but it seems `useEffect` is getting executed after `setParam()`.

So long story short, this is the order I want them to execute in:

1. setSelected()
2. useEffect() *(because of change in selected)*
3. setParam()

but they are executing in this order:

1. setSelected()
2. setParam()
3. useEffect() *(because of change in selected)*

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: can you show where `funcA` and `funcB` are being called?

Comment: Make your action asynchronous, because, when any action take time, javascript passes away, please see the link- [Async Actions | Redux](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions), you can also see this tutorial- [Async Actions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h892pHdLQtM)

Comment: @RedBaron funcA is just a button whereas funcB renders a table on a different page(It is a Sinigle page application. what i mean is the previous comp. is unmounted). So when user clicks on the funcA button he is redirected to the page with the table from funcB along with the loaded data(what we modified in the store)

Comment: why do you want to setParam to to be `b` then immediately set it to be an empty array in user effect?

Comment: @RedBaron useEffects sets the default value of param in usual conditions but here I want to recreate a page with some data using funcA. Also I dont want it to be set to empty array(_default value_), I want it to be set to [2, 3] which comes from the data I loaded.

Comment: @AnuragYadav setSelected is not taking time. Its just that setSelected triggers useEffect() which gets executed after setParam().

Comment: can you give us an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and then I can try and give you an actual answer

Comment: @SaranshAgarwal, I'm not talking time in milliseconds, seconds or hour, between any two functions which takes more time to complete it's execution, will complete execution after the second function, it doesn't matters which function started first. Please, follow the link in above comment and see the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the react world you should generally not rely on the *order* in which your setSomething() functions are called.

React "collects" state update calls, and decides the most efficient way to update the state.

Instead of thinking in *"call order"*, you should think in *"what should state B be if state A is X ?"*.
Instead of *"change state if user clicks"*, think of *"what does the user want so get/see ?"*.

Not good:

1. setSelected()
2. useEffect() (because of change in selected)
3. setParam()

Better:

1. setSelected()
2. useEffect() (calls setParam(), because of change in selected)
3. useEffect() (calls setParam(), because of ... why ?)

You probably have to rethink, and change the structure of your state a bit.

Comment: After trying few things I did just this and removed useEffect() and changed where I updated my variables. Thanks a lot @kicia